# Angular Universal SSR - TypeError: Cannot set property 'highcharts' of undefined

Tags: angular, highcharts, server-side-rendering

I have configured my angular 8 application for server side rendering. As expected, it's buggy on build and serve. I have fixed multiple issues including windows, document, localStorage e.t.c.
Now, I can't seem to get passed HIGHCHARTS library.
below is my import:

```
const $ = require("jquery");
const Highcharts = require('highcharts');

require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
```

I get errors as below:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'parts/Globals.js' of undefined`

I've been on this for hours. Any help?

When I take out the second line for exporting, I get

`TypeError: Cannot set property 'highcharts' of undefined`

Comment: Hi @Ifeanyi Chukwu, That looks like typical problem with a lack of global window object. Please check this thread for possible solutions: https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs/issues/57

Comment: I have imported window/document and other known objects of the global scope. Just can't get passed this one.

Comment: Please try to use the solution from @KacperMadej from this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10588